# IIS App Pool;Domain Admin password changed, now seeing errors in event viewer

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

We recently had to change a domain admin password due to a security issue. As a result, on our prod web server, we're seeing a large number of Event ID 4625 errors showing up in our security log associated with an IIS App Pool. We're on Windows 2012 R2/IIS 8.5; ASP.NET 2.0 & 4.0 are installed on the system.

The interesting piece is that the App Pool in question never used the domain admin account as its Identity. It has always used the out of the box ApplicationPoolIdentity. I should also note that the server was logged off using that affected user well prior to the password change & a new account is now used to administer the server.

The server itself though was in fact built using the affected domain admin account. All roles/features were added while logged in as the aforementioned account. With this in mind, no services are running as the account, ie World Wide Web Publishing Service/IIS Admin service. They're running as Local System & always have.

No functionality has been compromised, everything is operating normally on the web server. The issue is that our tech services team is receiving constant notifications from their account monitoring software regarding the bad logon attempts & it is impeding their operations. Full disclosure... We haven't had an opportunity to reboot the server yet since its production, we will be doing that tonight.

The problem seems to be relegated to the root of the site, the \wwwroot folder. Segregating only the root app to its own app pool/turning off the pool is not an option since it services file system requests. We've tried explicitly setting the identity on the affected app pool to use Local Service as well as a regular domain user. The issue persists regardless:

[image]

[image]

So naturally, our hope is that the reboot takes care of it... Perhaps the old password is stuck in a kerberos cache, but it's just strange since this app pool never used the ID as its identity, that it continues to show up.

Comment: maybe is in the app pool settings the options load user profile set to true ?

Comment: It is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

We had a virtual directory that was using the ID in order to reach out to a CIFS share on the network. Once we changed that, the error ceased.